# Как сгруппировать и суммировать данные в List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Есть класс

```
  class DB
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public decimal Summa { get; set; }
        public string Kontragent { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть данные

```
1    10    Apple
1    20    Apple  
1    10    Apple
2    20    Apple
2    9     Apple
2    8     Apple
1    4     Bosch
1    2     Bosch
```

Как с помощью `linq` сгруппировать и суммировать их, чтобы на выходе получилось

```
  1    30  Apple
  2    37  Apple
  1    6   Bosch
```

Comment: задача-то проще простого. домашка что ли? ладн, ответ: `items.GroupBy(i => i.Month)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так думаю

```
var newList = db.GroupBy( item => new {item.Month, item.Kontragent})
                .Select(item => new { Month = item.Key.Month, 
                                      Kontragent = item.Key.Kontragent, 
                                      Sum = item.Sum( value => value.Summa ) 
            });
```

Comment: Не проще ли использовать [перегрузку с `resultSelector`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__)?

Comment: @PavelMayorov  думаю в основе у обоих одно и тоже. Только вот который читабельнее?